# chroot mount real /root

Tags: linux, chroot

I have sample question in Linux.

I create chroot environment, but I want to have for example same `/root` for my real system and my chroot environment.

When I take this command:

```
chroot /mysystem
```

I want to access in my real `/root`, not "virtual" `/root`, can I mount `/root` in my chroot system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to bind-mounting the original root into the chroot, eg:

```
mount --bind / /chroot/root
chroot /chroot
```